# Switch to last opened file with one shortcut

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm just switching back from Spacemacs to Neovim, and I'm missing a quite useful feature: with <kbd>SPACE</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> I could switch to the previous opened file.

Example:

```
:e file_a.txt
:e file_b.txt
```

If I type <kbd>SPACE</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>, it would switch to `file_a.txt`. If I type <kbd>SPACE</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>, it would switch back to `file_b.txt`

How can I get the same in (neo)Vim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#CTRL-%5e

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>^</kbd> Edit the alternate file.  Mostly the alternate file is the previously edited file.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the standard, you can map

```
:nnoremap <Space><Tab> :e#<CR>
```

There is also another default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>6</kbd>.

Comment: I would do `:nnoremap <Space><Tab> <C-^>` personally

Answer (score 0):

if you have opened your files with 
  vim -p FirstFile SecondFile
You can switch between files with 
  gt and gT.